# How to ignore values of an integer for a coverpoint?

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog

I have a variable that is defined as an int and wants to create a `coverpoint` for this variable but I want to ignore values greater than 16384. How can I do this?

I have tried two things that haven't worked.

1. int acl;

   `int acl;
    acl: coverpoint (ccr_pkt.acl) {
             ignore_bins acl = {[16384:$]}; 
       }`
2. acl :

   `coverpoint (ccr_pkt.acl) iff (ccr_pkt.acl < 16384) {
            }`

Neither have worked. There were still bins created for values of acl greater than 16384.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), you need to specify bins to hit. As soon as you specify any kind of bin for a coverpoint, there are no implicit bins created.

For 2), `iff` does not control bin creation, it only affects sampling.

You should use:

```
acl: coverpoint (ccr_pkt.acl) {
          bins b[] = {[0:16383]}; }
```